# Pandas replace from multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to manipulate some data exported from a staff group that includes manager name and department. I am trying to uniform the data

I have the first line of code that works on only one condition, this modifies the data for all rows where this is true

```
def departmentTidy():
adImport['department'] = adImport['department'].replace({
    "Facilities":"UK Facilities",
    })
```

but my problem is that sometimes the department needs to be modified based on the original department & the manager - so all the rows that this is true for need to be replaced

```
def tidyDeptManagers():
if adImport['department']=="Finance" and adImport['ManagerEmail']=="manager.1@someEmail.com":
    adImport['department'] = adImport['department'].replace({
        "Finance":"Finance for manager 1"
    })
elif adImport['department']=="Finance" and adImport['ManagerEmail']=="manager.2@someEmail.com":
    adImport['orgidnumber'] = adImport['orgidnumber'].replace({
        "Finance":"Finance for manager 2"
    })
elif adImport['department']=="Finance" and adImport['ManagerEmail']=="manager.3@someEmail.com":
    adImport['orgidnumber'] = adImport['orgidnumber'].replace({
        "Finance":"Finance for manager 3"
    })
```

the problem is that the code keeps crashing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.
Also, share your error so we know why it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

turns out I wasnt looking at the problem in its simplest form

the code here did what I wanted

```
def tidyDeptManagers():
adImport.loc[(adImport['department'] =="Finance") & (adImport['ManagerEmail'] =="manager.1@someEmail.com"), 'department'] = 'Finance for manager 1'
adImport.loc[(adImport['department'] =="Finance") & (adImport['ManagerEmail'] =="manager.2@someEmail.com"), 'department'] = 'Finance for manager 2'
adImport.loc[(adImport['department'] =="Finance") & (adImport['ManagerEmail'] =="manager.3@someEmail.com"), 'department'] = 'Finance for manager 3'
```

there is probably a better way of doing this but this works perfectly for my needs